# Filtering nested lists

Tags: r, list, data-access

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994007/accessing-multiple-nth-elements-lists-from-nested-lists), as I have trouble extracting the data that I need using the `Filter` and `lapply` functions. Let's say I have the following data (which is of course only an excerpt):

```
result <- list(
  list(
    startSize = 2, method = "pa",
    list(time = 0.0016831, pk = c(1, 0), ij = c(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    list(time = 0.0002714, pk = c(1.1), ij = c(0)),
    list(time = 5.26e-05, pk = c(), ij = c())
  ),
  list(
    startSize = 2, method = "pa",
    list(time = 0.0004191, pk = c(2, 0), ij = c(22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    list(time = 0.0002401, pk = c(0.5, 1.2), ij = c(0)),
    list(time = 5.28e-05, pk = c(), ij = c())
  ),
  list(
    startSize = 4, method = "pnb",
    list(time = 0.0009156, pk = c(3, 0, 0, 0), ij = c(33, 0, 0, 0,0, 0)),
    list(time = 0.0010072, pk = c(4, 0, 0, 0), ij = c(44, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    list(time = 0.0005579, pk = c(5, 0), ij = c(55, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0))
  ),
  list(
    startSize = 4, method = "pnb",
    list(time = 0.0009364, pk = c(6, 0, 0, 0), ij = c(66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    list(time = 0.0023319, pk = c(7, 0, 0, 0), ij = c(77, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.33, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    list(time = 0.0013074, pk = c(8, 0), ij = c(8.8, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0))
  )
)
```

As you can see, I have a list containing `4` nested lists; I have `2` different `startSize`s (`2`/`4`), `2` different `method`s (`pa`, `pnb`) and each experiment was run `2` times. Each experiment contains `3` iterations and the `time` is recorded, together with 2 vectors `pk` and `ij`.

Based on @r2evens answer in the other question, I was hoping to

- write functions to make filtering easier, for example something like

```
myFilterFunction1 <- function(mylist, size, meth) {
  return(mylist["startSize"] == size && mylist["method"] == meth)
}
```

or

```
myFilterFunction2 <- function(mylist, size, meth) {
  return Filter(function(z) z["startSize"] == size && z["method"] == meth, mylist)
}
```

which I can then use to further filter the date using `lapply`. Both these two functions give me an error (*"'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"*), so at this point I haven't even gotten to play around with `lapply`. :(

Here is the kind of output that I would like extract:

1. **times**: For `startSize=2`, `method="pa"`, get matrix

| times | ,1 | ,2 | ,3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, | 0.0016831 | 0.0002714 | 5.26e-05 |
| 2, | 0.0004191 | 0.0002401 | 5.28e-05 |

2. **vector lengths**: For vector `"pk"`, `startSize=2`, `method="pa"`, get matrix

| length(pk) | ,1 | ,2 | ,3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2, | 2 | 2 | 0 |

3. combined vector (so I can compare boxplots, means, etc.) **by iteration**.  For vector `"pk"`, `startSize=2`, `method="pa"`, get vectors

```
c(1, 0, 2, 0), c(1.1, 0.5, 1.2), c()
```

I feel like I'm so close, yet I could not get it to work the past 7 hours, so I would be very thankful for some help!

Thank you in advance!